# Concat 2 columns in where condition - criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have a sql query like this example:

> SELECT TB1.A,TB1.B, TB2.C FROM 
>   TB1 JOIN TB2 
>   WHERE  **TB1.A + TB2.C <= 10**

I want to create a *Predicate* for this SQL condition... **TB1.A + TB2.C <= 10**

```
 List<Predicate> where = new ArrayList<>();
 where.add(super.cb().lessThanOrEqualTo(???????,dto.getDataVerificarQuebraAcordo()));
```

How can i implement this Predicate?

any ideias??

Comment: clearly JPA Criteria uses fields not columns (and you havent told us what the fields are called), so use cb.concat perhaps ... on the fields

Answer (score 1):

If TB1.A and TB2.C are numeric (as SQL suggests), then such a predicate can be created as follows (tb2s is join that seems to be used already for select):

```
Predicate p = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(
  cb.sum(root.get("a"),tb2s.get("c")),   
  cb.literal(10));
```

If they are Strings, then one will concatenate them and create string literal expression instead:

```
  Predicate p2 = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(  
    cb.concat(root.get("a"),tb2s.get("c")), 
    cb.literal("10"));
```